# Validate API Response to 3rd Party Swagger in Python

Tags: python, swagger, json-schema-validator

I'm working on a 3rd party API integration, and am looking for an effective way to validate that the response I got back matches the swagger published by the 3rd party.

Wondering if there's a straightforward way of doing this in Python.